# I need to get soundcard drivers for klvl-w58w

Tags: drivers, sound, huawei

I just bought a Huawei Laptop klvl-w58w, and beside there's too little info about it's beheaviour with linux, I really need my soundcard working. Found that many are struggling with this, but I also suspect there're many laptops that use this chipset. Can anyone help me find it?

Comment: What brand is the sound card?

Comment: If its not a certified Laptop for Ubuntu Linux, drivers may not exist. It won't help, but Thinkpads or Dell are mostly 100% Linux compatible over the last 15 years. Usually bought used, they last for another 10 years.

Comment: Try running the command `alsamixer` This will grab soundcard information.

Comment: AMD ATI Radeon 5000 series. 
I can't  "unbuy" the computer.

Comment: Also, Alsamixer says its "acp" with no controls to adjust.
Kubuntu and ubuntu show only "dummy output". When connecting to bluetooth device, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  (depends if the device connects correctly or not)

Comment: Pavucontrol-qt shows a "HD Audio generic" entry, but no available profile.
Tried adding "options snd_hda_intel index=1" to /etc/modprobe.d/default.conf 
Tryed adding "radeon.audio=1" to grub config, (outdated solution, but I didn't know what else to try).